# Oracle Apex IG query on basis of userroles

Tags: oracle-apex

I have my interactive grid query:

```
select user_id,name,address,emp_date from emp;
```

If the user is  Admin, application item :ROLE=1, if user is Editor, :ROLE= 3.

Now if, :ROLE=1, then `select user_id,name,address,emp_Date from emp; -- should return all rows`

Else if :ROLE=3,
Then `select user_id,name,address,emp_date from emp where user_id = :APP_USER`

Something like the above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
select user_id,name,address,emp_date 
  from emp 
 where user_id = :APP_USER
    or :role = 1
```

Or you may want to create two regions with the same report and add security based on `role` to determine which to display.  I'd normally prefer a single region to manage.  But if, for example, you wanted to allow admins to create subscriptions on this interactive report, having a separate region would be necessary because interactive report subscriptions aren't aware of session context.  That is, when the subscription is processed, both `:APP_USER` and `:ROLE` would be `NULL` so if you use the single query approach, a subscription's results would be empty.